# Where can I find the GWR web chat?

Tags: uk, trains, online-resources

According to the [GWR Customer Charter](https://www.gwr.com/~/media/gwr/pdfs/our-business/passengers-charter/gwr-customer-charter-sept-15-web.pdf?la=en.) (PDF, 1.7 MiB), *If you’re travelling soon and need help straightaway, start a
web chat with one of our advisers*.  I have searched the GWR website, but I can't seem to find the link to the web chat.  How do I connect to it?

Answer (score 2):

After going over their website with a <s>fine tooth comb</s> casual glance, the only thing resembling a web chat I could find was an invitation to use [Facebook Messenger](https://fb.com/msg/gwruk), linked from their [contact us page](https://www.gwr.com/customer-service/contact). It's advertised as being available 24x7.

Comment: One possibility is that it only shows up when they're active.

Comment: @gerrit "If you need help, our team are on hand 24/7"

Comment: Facebook Messenger is essentially a chat mechanism and one that is already installed on a bazillion phones.  So it would cover their promised CS.